# Got a list and need to match at least one to all entries in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking at this table:

```
+--------------+------------+
| DepartmentId | EmployeeId |
+--------------+------------+
|            2 | Franc      |
|            1 | Peter      |
|            1 | Franc      |
|            1 | Simon      |
|            2 | Peter      |
+--------------+------------+
```

I have a list of Persons, in this example :employees {Franc,Peter}. So I want to find out where those two guys working BUT if another person is working there like Simon. I don't want to know.

I tried

```
Select departmentId from employeeId in :employees.
```

This gives me {1,2}. From a logical standpoint i just wanna have:

```
Select  deparmentId from employeeId "exactly" in :employees
```

So I want to get DepartmentId:2, because Simon is also working at Department 1. And I just want to know where Franc, Peter work there alone.

Comment: And at which point in constructing the SQL are you stuck?

Comment: Are you using Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: Ok Oracle and Java. Having an Array of names as pepared parameter. Tried to do it as 
    select * from company where employeeId in (franc,peter} 
but in this way i also get department 1 which i don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is three different ways of doing this:

```
SELECT DepartmentId 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DepartmentId
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN EmployeeId = 'Franc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN EmployeeId = 'Peter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND 
    COUNT(EmployeeId) = 2
```

The query should pretty self explaining; the having clause makes sure the department has both Franc and Peter, and that the count of employees is 2, meaning there can't be any other employees in that department.

The query below joins the set of departments where Franc works with the set of departments where Peter works and uses the`not in`clause to remove all departments where someone who isn't Franc or Peter works.

```
SELECT t1.DepartmentId FROM your_table t1 
JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.DepartmentId = t2.DepartmentId
WHERE t1.EmployeeId = 'Franc' AND t2.EmployeeId = 'Peter'
AND t1.DepartmentId NOT IN (
    SELECT DepartmentId 
    FROM your_table
    WHERE EmployeeId NOT IN ('Franc', 'Peter')
    )
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14b8d/1)

A third way is to use the SQL set operators `union`and `except`(or `minus`):

```
(
SELECT DepartmentId FROM your_table WHERE EmployeeId = 'Franc'
UNION ALL
SELECT DepartmentId FROM your_table WHERE EmployeeId = 'Peter'
)
EXCEPT
SELECT DepartmentId FROM your_table WHERE EmployeeId NOT IN ('Franc', 'Peter')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    employee e2
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT  COUNT(1) Occs,
                        Name
                FROM    employee E1
                GROUP BY Name
                Having COUNT(1) = 1 
                ) emps
        on e2.Name = emps.Name
```

Returns Simon, as he's the only one who works in only one department

Comment: I think this is opposite of what the OP is asking for; the objective is to find departments where both Franc and Peter work and no one else.